# Strong name signature not valid for the assembly System.IO.Compression.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I've created a tool for work using Visual Studio 2013, but when I publish the application so that my co-workers can test it, they always get the following error when attempting to install and run the application:

```
Strong name signature not valid for this assembly System.IO.Compression.dll
```

So far I've tried the following fixes, but nothing is working:

1) I've used sn.exe and the command sn -Vr *,publicKeyToken for System.IO.Compression using its publicKeyToken

2) I've checked the manifest for System.IO.Compression, and it does have a publicKeyToken

3) Inside my project, I've set "Copy Local" and "Specific Version" to TRUE for System.IO.Compression

I don't know if it's relevant, but I'm also getting this message in VS when building the solution:

```
1>c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll : warning CS1684: Reference to type 'System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel' claims it is defined in 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.dll', but it could not be found
1>c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll : warning CS1684: Reference to type 'System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel' claims it is defined in 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.dll', but it could not be found
1>c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.IO.Compression.dll : warning CS1684: Reference to type 'System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel' claims it is defined in 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.dll', but it could not be found
1>c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll : warning CS1684: Reference to type 'System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel' claims it is defined in 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.dll', but it could not be found
```

Here are the error details:

```
            Following errors were detected during this operation.
            * [6/1/2015 3:19:03 PM] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (SignatureValidation)
                            - Strong name signature not valid for this assembly System.IO.Compression.dll.
                            - Source: System.Deployment
                            - Stack trace:
                                            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentVerifier.VerifyStrongNameAssembly(String filePath, AssemblyManifest assemblyManifest)
                                            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentVerifier.VerifyComponents()
                                            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
                                            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
                                            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
                                            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
                                            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
```

UPDATE: I fixed the problem by reinstalling .NET and creating a new project from  scratch, then transferring over everything from my old project. Apparently something got really corrupted in the old project.

Comment: Looks like you're building for a framework you either do not have installed or have corrupted.

Comment: Do you mean that you think System.IO.Compression is corrupted? Or something else? If the dll file is corrupted, how would I refresh it? You can't just download that from somewhere off the internet. EDIT: If the .Net framework is corrupted, how would I fix that? My copy of VS is brand new.

Comment: Downloading it off the internet is fairly easy [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40773). It's possible your installation went bad - are you using the 2015 CTP?

Comment: No, I'm not using 2015 CTP. I have VS 2013 professional (update 3, I think). For the .Net installer link you gave me, would I just download and install it, or do I need to do something else?

Comment: Also, I added the XNA framework (plus update for 2013) on top of VS. Could that have corrupted it?

Comment: The fx installer should be "self-healing" and get you up to par. XNA isn't supported anymore (that I know of) and it very well could be the problem. It is very possible that the new framework (4.5.1) and XNA do not play well together. If that's the case, try down leveling to 3.5 or removing XNA.